# Looking for a script to forward keypresses from Windows to Linux

Tags: bluetooth, synergy

I have a Linux workstation, running Windows in VMWare, which has a full access to USB bluetooth dongle.

Just discovered that my phone has Bluetooth HID support, so Windows does receives some common keypresses (mouse left, mouse right, "next", "play", "pause" from it. But I want to retranslate those events to Linux host without having to re-plug bluetooth back to host.

This is just a temporary hack, so don't want to spend time on time; anyone knows of a ready-made script that can do such stuff - key pressed, key retranslated by to linux and sent out via  **xautomation**  package? Or anything like **Synergy**, but with ability to retranslate only specific keypresses?

P.S. If nothing such exists, that's not the problem - I just want to control VLC, and it has a remote web control which is suitable for me - a quick Freepascal program that will sit over other open windows and listen for keys and polls HTTP, or a Flash client and a Python server.. don't want to lose a hour in exchange for a wheel.

Comment: Or, will hack into synergy's code